# Kryonet Log no longer appearing

Tags: java, android, eclipse, kryonet

Previous to installing the android SDK on my Eclipse installation my Network project would always output anything from Log.info("STRING") to the output on screen.

Since I have installed the Android plug in for Eclipse anything that is generated from Log.info is no longer appearing on the output console.

Even exporting for example Server.java to a jar, the jar file will only output anything that is from System.out....
Using the com.esotericsoftware.minlog.Log; package for logging from the Kryonet package.

Comment: I would need more information about your configuration before I can answer your question. For instance, are you using the debug version of kryonet? Is this in an android project? If so you will need to use the LogCat instead of System.out by overriding the default logger in kryonet.